# Select part of a text with CSS selectors

Tags: text, css-selectors

Is is possible to select part of a text using just CSS selectors?

For example:

```
<p id="myparagraph">
Your order id is 7654. Thanks for your order.
</p>
```

I now I can select text from paragraph via `$('#myparagraph').html()`

But is it possible to select only the numbers 7654 from that text using just CSS selectors?

I'm not in control of the source HTML, so unfortunately I cannot alter the text.

Comment: No, it is not possible, select an element using part of its text content using css selector, probably i did not understand your question.

Comment: Just add <p class="select-this-thing">7654</p>, css can't regex.

Comment: @Winchestro: I'm not in control of the HTML...so I can't do that..updated my question. But your comment clarifies it `css can't regex`..is this perhaps something of which you know is coming in the future? I personally think it would be tremendously powerful :)

Comment: @Flo Not that I know of. you could implement it yourself maybe, if you are in control of the js (which you probably aren't otherwise you wouldn't ask :) I agree that it would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have use span tag like this

```
<p id="myparagraph">
Your order id is <span class="number">7654</span>. Thanks for your order.
</p>
```

After then you can write your css code by calling the selector like this.

```
span.number {
   color: red;
}
```